# Why PHP 8.1 Sodium PHP-Extension shows enabled but .iso file is not in extension folder

Tags: php, linux, php-extension, libsodium, php-8.1

Why the php cli command "php -m" and also phpinfo() both show "sodium" php-extension as enabled / loaded, although there is no sodium.iso file in extension folder "/usr/lib/php/20210902" and no *.ini file of no SAPI's showing as enabling it (instead, php.ini of each SAPI shows it commented, while inside conf.d there is nothing like xy-sodium.ini).

I am using Php version 8.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. I do not use lampp, xampp, wampp instead i install php versions from command line like:

```
sudo apt install php8.1 php8.1-dev php8.1-cli php8.1-fpm php8.1-xml php8.1-mysql libapache2-mod-php8.1 php8.1-common php8.1-zip php8.1-gd php8.1-mbstring php8.1-gettext php8.1-curl php8.1-bcmath php8.1-opcache php8.1-mcrypt php8.1-igbinary php8.1-intl
```

Comment: From my reading it was included in PHP 7.2+ and there's no need to turn on an extension as the code and functions should just work as normal